# reading a post from another site with a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I have a static html page with jQuery that receives a post from another website.  I need to be able to read the information in the post and store the data in a cookie, but the page is a static html page and has to stay that way.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So you're not allowed to use any programming language? I don't think that'd be possible

Comment: If the page is static, what are you using jQuery for? Or, what do you mean by "static page"? Probably the best answer to either of these questions would be some code/markup.

Comment: how will you receive the "post" from another website, xml? json?

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the information from the other website via an $.ajax() call in JSON or XML format then you can use the jQuery Cookie plugin (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to take the returned information and store it in a cookie.

Hope this helps.